# How would I go about using nrow() for multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I have imported a 'bank.csv' file into my workspace in R-Studio, the question is asking for me to  find the marital status of people who have only a primary education. Here is the code i used that I thought would give me the answe:

```
nrow(bank.df[bank.df$marital & bank.df$education == 'primary'])
```

but gave me an error:

```
nrow(bank.df[bank.df$marital & bank.df$education == 'primary'])
Error in bank.df$marital & bank.df$education == "primary" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

I am new to R and would like some advice for this.

Comment: You might want to pick a different title. This one makes it sound like you are looking for legal or social advice or something, not programming advice.

Comment: If your `bank.df$marital` is logicalthat should work.  Otherwise, you may need to convert to logical

Comment: the `nrow` function will not answer you the "what is the marital status"... but the following can list the marital status for you:  `bank.df[bank.df$education == 'primary',"marital"]`... maybe you will like to assess something like frequencies for each category after that...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by "find the marital status of people" alongside the `nrow`...

The `nrow` function will not answer you the "what is the marital status"... but the following can list the marital status for you:

```
bank.df[bank.df$education == 'primary',"marital"]...
```

maybe you will like to assess something like frequencies for each category after that...

But, if you want to filter the dataset by two conditions, and count the records which match the criteria, so, there is two main errors in your code:

- First: the `bank.df$marital & bank.df$education == 'primary'` the both parts (before and after `&`) needs to be a test..., for example:

  `bank.df$marital =='married'& bank.df$education == 'primary'`
- Second: You are filtering a data frame or a tible, so, the object has two dimensions... you are filtering rows, so...

  `bank.df[bank.df$marital =='married'& bank.df$education == 'primary',]`

Comment: Ah, okay that makes alot more sense.

Comment: @hydroflow happy to help. If the above answer helped you, can you accept the answer?